# Iterate array of objects in java

Tags: java

I am making a simple java application that asks user for the subject they want tutors for, and then prints the tutors teaching that subject.

This is what I've written so far.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tutor tutorOne = new Tutor("Anthony Joshua", "Mathematics", "31", "London, England");
        Tutor tutorTwo = new Tutor("Andy Ruiz", "Physics", "31", "Mexico City, Mexico");
        Tutor tutorThree = new Tutor("Vitali Klitschko", "Computer Science", "49", "Saint Petersberg, Russia");
        Tutor tutorFour = new Tutor("Ray Leonard", "Mathematics", "64", "North Carolina, USA");
        Tutor[] allTutors = {tutorOne, tutorTwo, tutorThree, tutorFour};
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the subject: ");
        String tutorNeeded = userInput.nextLine();
        if (tutorNeeded.contains("Math")) {
            System.out.println(tutorOne.name+"\n"+tutorOne.subject+"\n"+tutorOne.age+"\n"+tutorOne.location);
        }else if (tutorNeeded.contains("Physics")) {
            System.out.println(tutorTwo.name+"\n"+tutorTwo.subject+"\n"+tutorTwo.age+"\n"+tutorTwo.location);
        } else if (tutorNeeded.contains(("Computer"))) {
            System.out.println(tutorThree.name+"\n"+tutorThree.subject+"\n"+tutorThree.age+"\n"+tutorThree.location);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, we don't have any tutors for that subject availible right now.");
        }
    }
    static class Tutor {
        String name;
        String subject;
        String age;
        String location;

        Tutor(String name, String subject, String age, String location) {
            this.name = name;
            this.subject = subject;
            this.age = age;
            this.location = location;
        }
    }
}
```

How would I make it so that when the user types "Maths", they get shown tutor 1 as well as tutor 4?
I could do this manually, but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all objects using either a normal `for`-Loop or a `foreach`-Loop in your `main` function, depending on you Java version:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allTutors.length; i++) {
    Tutor t = allTutors[i];
    if (t.subject.contains(tutorNeeded)) {
        System.out.println(t.name + "\n" + t.subject + "\n" + t.age + "\n" + t.location);
    }
}
```

Using the `forEach`-Loop:

```
for (Tutor t : allTutors) {
    if (t.subject.contains(tutorNeeded)) {
        System.out.println(t.name + "\n" + t.subject + "\n" + t.age + "\n" + t.location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked and I also learned how to do this in the future. You have no idea how much you saved me..

Comment: @BatmanTheReal No problem! Don't forget to upvote and mark the most helpful answer out of all these here :)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate or stream the array of tutors, and filter accordingly. E.g.:

```
Arrays.stream(allTutors)
      .filter(t -> t.subject.contains(tutorNeeded))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note:
The `System.out.println` call at the end relies on the `Tutor` class overriding the `toString()` method, which you should probably do regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Map that holds key as user type and value as the tutor object. When user types a input just grab that using map.get(USERINPUT) it will return you the object.

Comment: A ``Map`` is way to overkill for this. Also for extensibility, it is not the way to go.